# Limits and Inequalities

Tags: real-analysis

My book claims the following: Let $f$ be a continuous function. $\lim s_n = x_0$ and since $f(s_n) < y$ for all $n$, we have $f(x_0) = \lim f(s_n) \leq y$. Can someone explain why the last inequality is $\leq$ and not just $<$?

I feel like I am missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $f(s_n) \in \{x \mid f(x)<y \}$, so $f(x_0)= \lim f(s_n)$ is in the closure of $\{x \mid f(x)<y \}$ which is precisely $\{x \mid f(x) \leq y\}$ (I assumed $f$ continuous).

Comment: Yes thanks for mentioning that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Simple example: If $s_n=-\frac1n$ and $f(x)=x$ then $f(s_n)<0$ for all $n$ but $f(x_0)=0$ (as of course $\lim s_n=0$)

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) = -\dfrac1x$, then $f(x) < 0$ for all (positive) $x$, but $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$.