# Calculating a Squeeze Theorem limit

Tags: calculus

Find $$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$$ when $$\frac{6x^2-1}{3x^2} \le f(x) \lt \frac{2x^3+x+3}{x^3}$$.

I applied L'Hospital's Rule to the left and right functions, and got $2$ for both of them. However, this expression then simplifies to:

$$\frac{12x}{6x} \le \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) \lt \frac{6x^2 + 1}{3x^2}$$
$$\frac{12}{6} \le \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) \lt \frac{12x}{6x}$$
$$\frac{12}{6} \le \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) \lt \frac{12}{6}$$
$$2 \le \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) \lt 2$$

How does this make sense? If $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ is $2$, then that satisfies the left equality because the limit can be $2$ (less than or equal to), but then that would not satisfy the right equality because the limit cannot be 2 (only less than 2).

Am I taking the wrong approach to solving this problem?

Comment: Related: [Limits and Inequalities](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417919/limits-and-inequalities). The *strictness* of inequalities is not preserved when taking limits.

Comment: No need to use L'Hopital's Rule. The limit of both sides can be easily calculated to be $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh no, do not worry. It is possible that $f(x) < \frac{2x^3+x+3}{x^3}$ for every value of $x$, yet $\lim_{x\to 2} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{2x^3+x+3}{x^3}$. To give an obvious example, let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{2x^3+x+3}{x^3}+\frac{6x^2-1}{3x^2}\Big)$. Then $f(x)$ follows the conditions, and $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) =2$, which is expected by squeeze theorem.

Moral of the story : limits do not preserve strict inequality, they preserve it with the possibility of equality.

---

Edit:  L'Hopital may preserve strict inequality, but there is no need to evaluate these limits using that rule.

$\frac{6x^2-1}{3x^2} = 2 - \frac{1}{3x^2}$, so $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{6x^2-1}{3x^2} = 2$.

$\frac{2x^3+x+3}{x^3} = 2 + \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{3}{x^3}$, so $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x^3+x+3}{x^3} = 2$.

That's all, now use squeeze theorem and conclude.

Comment: Maybe he does not need to worry, but it is not so evident to me that l'Hopital preserves inequalities (as the OP suggests).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thank you for the clarification. There is no need to use L'Hopital's rule. Both limits can be evaluated by partial fractions.